# C++: How to "hit enter automatically" after a character has been entered?

Tags: c++, macos, stdin

I'm currently working on a text based game using C++.  The player moves around by pressing W, A, S, and D.  However, in order to make a move, the player must press the movement key and then hit enter, which is annoying.

I did a bit of research on how to make the program automatically take the input after one character was entered, but I only found solutions for Windows (using the `conio.h` header file)

Is there any way to achieve this on OS X?  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/

Comment: @Aurel300 wrong. Have you tried it?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use the `ncurses` library, which will not only allow you to get key presses immediately, but also paint your game scene nicely.

Comment: @Aurel300 that returns a char from stdin, but it is not automatic

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I'll give it a look

Comment: @n.m. Yup, my bad :)

Comment: [ncurses lib](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/)

Comment: @Gernot1976 `I did a bit of research on how to make the program automatically take the input after one character was entered, but I only found solutions for Windows (using the conio.h header file)`

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I got it working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)